# Decrease spacing between sections in UICollectionView List Layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` using a `.insetGrouped`  `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration`.

I like the appearance of the rounded items, so instead of using *rows* I'm using a section for each of my items. However due to the section spacing, things look a little odd and I'd like to decrease it.

I've tried setting the both the `separatorConfiguration` and `itemSeparatorHandler` to have a top and bottom inset of `.zero` with no luck

How can I decrease this spacing?

[image]

Comment: Are you using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` or `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`?

Comment: Compositional List Layout

Comment: I would suggest costuming each row and altering the `cornerRadius` on the cell as spacing is a lot more customisable. On the `NSCollectionLayoutItem` you can change the `contentInsets.bottom` value. Sharing your source code would help

Comment: Given your screenshot, why not use a UITableView with `insetGrouped` style?

Answer (score 1):

When using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, vertical padding between sections is configured using the `contentInsets` property on `NSCollectionLayoutSection`. This applies whether you're using a list configuration, or a custom layout section definition.

Make sure you're using the section provider initializer for `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` so you can customize properties on the `NSCollectionLayoutSection` for each list section. For example:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment in
    
    let listConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: listConfig, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)

    // Remove the default vertical padding between sections
    var contentInsets = section.contentInsets
    contentInsets.top = 0
    contentInsets.bottom = 0
    section.contentInsets = contentInsets
    
    return section
}
```